# DAX query for KPI tracking

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: data image]

i am trying to write a query in order to track penalty in case of KPI failure.
eg. if in month of Oct my PI is failed 98% i get a retention if fail again following month not i get another retention i get deduction. In case one month its 98% and next month i pass i get money back.

below is the formula in excel need to change them in DAX any suggestions please.

**Frist month retention formula**       =IF(AND(F4>=0.98,F4<1),E4,"")
**following month deduction **          =IF(AND(F5<1,F5>=0.98,J5<1,J5>=0.98),E5,IF(AND(J5<0.98,F5<0.98),I5,IF(AND(F5<1,F5>=0.98,J5<0.98),E5+I5,IF(AND(F5=1,J5<0.98),I5,""))))

**refund of retention in case of pass** =IF(AND(N5=1,J5<1,J5>=0.98),-K5,IF(AND(N5<1,N5>=0.98,J5<1,J5>=0.98),M5,IF(AND(J5=1,N5<1,N5>=0.98),M5,IF(AND(J5<0.98,N5<1,N5>=0.98),M5,""))))

Comment: let alone all these disorderness, At least show us where those column titles on the image!

Comment: sorry trying to add the data but system not letting, i will try again to post this question

Comment: Please the link for the data now